# How to maintain 'master' branch as a series of release commits

Tags: git, github, git-merge

In a lot of different open source projects, the 'master' branch contains only commits that denote a release of the project (for example: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commits/master)

[image]

My question is - is there any trick for achieving this?
I assume the development is performed on another branch, but how should the merge/sync back into master make it into a "clean" single commit per release ?

Comment: One merge to master = one merge commit = one release

Comment: usually with a merge, i can actually see what branch was merged into master, as well as the whole history of commits

Comment: git flow? https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html

Comment: @nbari your point being ?

Comment: @lysergic-acid by following gitflow, like you indeed mentioned development is in another branch and only releases tagged in many cases using [semver](https://github.com/nbari/semverbump) are merged into master

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what other projects do you mean, but `facebook/facebook-android-sdk` does not do what you think it does. These are regular commits with names that look like release. You can see what was changed in release by comparing 2 tags:

- [4.32](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/compare/sdk-version-4.31.0...sdk-version-4.32.0) - 5 commits
- [4.31](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/compare/sdk-version-4.30.0...sdk-version-4.31.0) - 2 commits
- [4.30](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/compare/sdk-version-4.29.0...sdk-version-4.30.0) - 5 commits

You can find all these commits in master history:

[image]

The only "trick" here is that regular development is done in [dev branch](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/dev), and it is merged to master only on release, so master always contains last stable release.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with a squash merge, that combines all commits from the branch in a single commit that will be added to the master branch.